# Lots of unlabeled data and small set of labelled data of one class

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, semi-supervised-learning, one-class

Does anyone have suggestions for specific algorithm or implementation for labeled data of only one class and unlabeled data that can be from either classes? And I'm unsure what is the proportion of Class A to B that exists within the unlabeled data and also my labeled data is not randomly chosen. I have tried many ways like one-class classification, UPlearning but they don't return high accuracy. Can you please help me with that?